# Apache Spark / Scala: How to get all the elements of an array except the last one?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to get all possible subdomains from the domain name, such as:
`www.abc.xyz.com`, and I have an array `(www.abc.xyz.com,abc.xyz.com,xyz.com,com)`. Now I want to explode this array into:

- `www.abc.xyz.com`
- `abc.xyz.com`
- `xyz.com`

but I do not want the last element: com

Note that the size of the array can vary.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance for all the help!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why is this post tagged with `apache-spark` and `spark-dataframe`? The post doesn't mention anything specific to Spark. Are you interested in a way to perform this transformation over a dataframe _column_? If so, mention that (and give a code example of what you already have) to get more precise/useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Scala has a nice function for this. It is called as `dropRight`:

```
arr.dropRight(n)
```

This will drop all the last "n" elements. It also handles exceptional cases. E.g. if your array length < n then it will simply return empty array.

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html

Comment: @MeenaAthmanathan Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks!!

Comment: There is also an `arr.init` method, but it's unsafe (same as `arr.tail`, but removing first on the right, not left). I give it for completeness sake, but `dropRight` is (almost) always the way to go.